# Finding lined-up elements in a list

Tags: python, list

How to efficiently find lined-up elements (list2) in a list (list1)?

E.g.:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
list2 = ['d', 'e']
```

In this case the index, since there is a match, would be 3.

The actual data is a string like this (in fact, literally, all whitespace is there), which I intend to split, and remove whitespace:

```
  +--head (1)                                                                          
  |  +--title (1)                                                                      
  |  +--meta (3)                                                                       
  |  +--link (14)                                                                      
  |  +--script (21)                                                                    
  |  +--comment (3)                                                                    
  |  +--noscript (1)                                                                   
  |     +--iframe (1)
```

And I'm trying to match:

```
+--link (14)                                                                      
+--script (21)
```

In the real data the index would be where `+--link` starts.

Comment: Really reminds me of finding a substring in a string, but I wonder what is an efficient algorithm in python to do this?

Comment: Is there no other info available? Sorted? Big? Multiple?

Comment: It looks like you want to do a linear search. I don't see any shortcuts in this scenario. Can 'd' or 'e' occur more than once?

Comment: Would the downvoters care to leave a comment? Closer: what is too broad about it now?

Comment: @keyser Is there an easy implementation in python?

Comment: @PascalvKooten - I was one downvoted this question because it shows no research effort (no attempted solutions).  Whether you have 4 rep or 4,000, all users must follow the [guidelines for asking a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as listed in the Help Center.  I'd be happy to remove the downvote if you amend your post.

Comment: @iCodez Not all questions on Stackoverflow require (and have) attempts. I simplified the question such that it is an easy to solve question for the community. You can see that my actual problem was much larger, and that I've simplified it down to where my issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this. Maybe will work fine.

```
def get_sublist_index(list1, list2):
    l1, l2 = len(list1), len(list2)
    for i in range(l1-l2):
        if list1[i:i+l2] == list2:
            return i
```

Comment: I was really overthinking that one... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index of where that '+--link' start you can just use the following :

```
>>> len(s.split('+--link')[0])
269
```

first split your string based on `+--link` then the length of first slice is the index of where that '+--link' has beed started !

Comment: I'm only interested in finding `+--link` if it is actually followed by that `+--script` after the newline.

Comment: can you say pls what you want at all ? do you want the index or the string ?

Comment: The index, Simeon Popov gave the answer.